# Oracle SQL, getting repeated result on a hierarchical query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query against two tables `workorder` and `classstructure`. I am trying to get a workorder that it's id equals `000000004140094` along with it's classification path. (the parent of that path is `1688`).

```
SELECT
W.WONUM,
W.STATUS,
W.ASSETNUM,
LPAD (' ', 2 * LEVEL - 1) || SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (c.CLASSIFICATIONID, '/') PATH
FROM MAXIMO.WORKORDER W
LEFT  JOIN CLASSSTRUCTURE C ON W.CLASSSTRUCTUREID = C.CLASSSTRUCTUREID
WHERE WONUM ='000000004140094'
START WITH c.parent = '1688'
CONNECT BY PRIOR TO_CHAR (c.CLASSSTRUCTUREID) = c.PARENT
```

how ever I get the repeated result like below whereas I only need one result (the WONUM is unique):

```
WONUM       STATUS      ASSETNUM       PATH
000000004140094 COMP        51110          /CM/POSTFAILCM
000000004140094 COMP        51110          /CM/POSTFAILCM
000000004140094 COMP        51110          /CM/POSTFAILCM
000000004140094 COMP        51110          /CM/POSTFAILCM
000000004140094 COMP        51110          /CM/POSTFAILCM
000000004140094 COMP        51110          /CM/POSTFAILCM
000000004140094 COMP        51110          /CM/POSTFAILCM
000000004140094 COMP        51110          /CM/POSTFAILCM
```

I just wanted to know what I am doing wrong or maybe I have to rewrite my query in general.

edit: structure of two tables

Workorder table:

```
WONUM       STATUS  ASSETNUM    CLASSSTRUCTUREID
000000000108085 CLOSE   00199928    1000
000000000108247 CLOSE   00202763    1061
000000000108248 CLOSE   00202763    1061
000000000108273 CLOSE   00199790    1000
```

Classstructure table:

```
CLASSSTRUCTUREID  PARENT    CLASSIFCATIONID
1688                             FLT
1689              1688           ASSET
1690              1688           PMFLT
1691              1688           CM
1692              1691           POSTFAILCM
```

Comment: as it looks you´re hirarchy is present within the `classstructure` table, which is a detail of `workorder`. You´re building the hirarchy for the details but simply keep repeating the master data entry, which might explain the repeated result. Though without knowing how the tables are correlated to each other it´s pretty impossible to find a flaw there.

Comment: Could you please post the structure of the two tables? We don't need the entire table, just the columns you are working with. Also could you create few sample records?

Comment: yes I have to get the hierarchy from the `classstructure` table. and I know that the parent of the classification id equals `1688`. I have to build this since it's not represented as the path shown above in the `classstructure` table.

Comment: @abhi, I added the table structures.

Comment: use `START WITH c.parent IS NULL`

Comment: @KaushikNayak I did that but my query took a very long time to run. However, Thorsten Kettner's query below did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this step by step:

- Get the path hierarchy (FLT, FLT/ASSET, FLT/PMFLT, FLT/CM, FLT/CM/POSTFAILCM) starting with all root paths (i.e. no parent; only FLT in your sample data)
- Join to the '000000004140094' record

Using standard SQL's recursive `WITH` clause:

```
with paths(classstructureid, path) as
(
  select classstructureid, classifcationid as path
  from classstructure 
  where parent is null
  union all
  select c.classstructureid, p.path || '/' || c.classifcationid as path
  from classstructure c
  join paths p on p.classstructureid = c.parent
)
select
  w.wonum,
  w.status,
  w.assetnum,
  p.path
from workorder w
join paths p on p.classstructureid = w.classstructureid
where w.wnum = '000000004140094';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your duplication issue is where you specify the condition of your root

```
START WITH c.parent = '1688'
```

This isn't specifying the root record, this condition would match all the records one level down (or is it up?) from your root.

To specify your root record it should be

```
START WITH c.classstructureid = '1688'
```